# python common list of values from two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
a = [1, 2, 4]

b = [9, 2,2,2,3,3, 4,4]

c= set(a) & set(b)

print(c)
```

Result : `{2, 4}`

i need it like : `{2,2,2,4,4}`

Thank you

Comment: did you try anything? Please show some effort.
Note that `set()` cannot contain duplicates (but a list can).

Comment: Did you try anything ? You could use dictionaries with setdefault and a counter ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the duplicates in the result to correspond to the duplicates in `b`.
(as in your example)

```py
c= [i for i in b if i in a]
```

output:

```py
[2, 2, 2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: What if contents of `a` and `b` are swapped?

Comment: @Prudhvi the assumption is stated in the answer.  It is unclear what would be desired result (if any) in hypothetical cases such as duplicates in `a` or duplicates in both `a` and `b`.